# Can someone list all the possible supported values for "field" in the Azure Policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-policy

It's becoming hectic to find the values for the "field" when writing the custom policies.

Some of the values of the built-in values for "field" are:

- type
- location
- name
- tags
- kind
- Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sku.name
- Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/supportsHttpsTrafficOnly
- Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/networkAcls.ipRules
- Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher
- Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type
- Microsoft.Sql/transparentDataEncryption.status
- Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/allowBlobPublicAccess
- Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits/serviceProvider.bandwidthInMbps
- Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules

Please feel free to add more if you guys can come across anything. Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly you are looking into!

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the fields that can be used in custom policy rules to define conditions when the policy is enforced, here is the list from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#policy-rule):

- name
- fullName
- kind
- type
- location
- id
- tags
- tags['<tagName>']
- property [aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#aliases)

Note that the list of aliases is constantly growing. The best way to find what aliases are currently supported by Azure Policy is to use the [Azure Policy extension for Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/extension-for-vscode). It allows to view and discover aliases for resource properties:
[image: Azure Policy extension for Visual Studio Code]

It is also possible to get the list of aliases using Azure PowerShell:

```
# Login first with Connect-AzAccount if not using Cloud Shell

# Use Get-AzPolicyAlias to list available providers
Get-AzPolicyAlias -ListAvailable

# Use Get-AzPolicyAlias to list aliases for a Namespace (such as Azure Compute -- Microsoft.Compute)
(Get-AzPolicyAlias -NamespaceMatch 'compute').Aliases
```

Azure CLI and REST API methods are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#aliases) too.